# Why was "Derivative Definition & Limits" deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deletion

Why was [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41676/derivative-definition-limits) deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP was suspended for posting a string of homework questions without accepting answers and without listening to multiple comments by other users. I didn't want any answers to be posted to those questions in the meantime, and I also didn't want them clogging up the main page. (But I am open to suggestions about what to do in these situations.)

Comment: I'd suggest not deleting questions that already have answers posted, especially if the question (independent of the asker) has substance/merit/etc.

Comment: Fair enough. The questions have been undeleted.